# using ion_auth with different languages

Tags: codeigniter, internationalization, ion-auth

I am trying to use [ion_auth](http://benedmunds.com/ion_auth/) with different languages

the default is English I guess and I am trying to use French

**controller**

```
class Auth extends CI_Controller {

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('ion_auth');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->helper('url');

    // Load MongoDB library instead of native db driver if required
    $this->config->item('use_mongodb', 'ion_auth') ?
    $this->load->library('mongo_db') :

    $this->load->database();

    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters($this->config->item('error_start_delimiter', 'ion_auth'), $this->config->item('error_end_delimiter', 'ion_auth'));

    $this->lang->load('auth','french');
    $this->load->helper('language');

            /*    $lang = $this->session->userdata('lang_name');
    if(!isset($lang))
    { //load default language 
      $this->lang->load('site');
      $this->lang->load('ion_auth');
      $this->lang->load('auth');
    }
    else
    { //load language from session
     // print_r('lang :'.$this->session->userdata('lang_name'));
      $this->lang->load('site',$this->session->userdata('lang_name'));
      $this->lang->load('ion_auth',$this->session->userdata('lang_name'));
      $this->lang->load('auth',$this->session->userdata('lang_name'));
    }*/


}
```

its always on english never changes to french or some other language

```
<?php
    $this->lang->load('auth','french');
?>
```

I have tried also the above on the view and nothing never changes to french

Comment: Where is the code you are using to output the language lines?

Comment: please try go to configuration `config/config.php` and see line `$config['language'] = 'english';` try to change it to desired language, this wont't help that much to solve your problem. Make sure you've translated CI to french.

Answer (score 1):

you have to change your language in `CI->config.php`

chnage this `$config['language']= 'english'; to $config['language']= 'french';`

for your reference 
https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth/issues/472

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, and this is working, but i don't know or it safe. In Ion_auth file ( in libraries folder - codeigniter framework)

```
find public function __construct()

change: $this->lang->load('ion_auth');
to: $this->lang->load('ion_auth',trim($this->input->post('language')));
```

thats all

etc...

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change the language for system wide you must dynamically edit config items. For example;

```
 if (isset($set_language)) {
    $this->lang->load('auth','french');
    $this->config->set_item('language','french');
}
```